# Calculating sum of fractions- weights on denominator

Tags: arithmetic, fractions

Suppose that you wish to add two fractions:
$$
\frac{x}{y}+\frac{a}{b}
$$
Of course, there are many ways one can proceed. One way to write this
would be:
$$
A=\frac{xb+ay}{yb}
$$
Now, is there any way to express $A$ as a ``weighted average''
of the denominators $y$ and $b,$ such that:
$$
A=\frac{\phi x+\gamma a}{\omega y+\left(1-\omega\right)b}
$$
Intuitively, there must be a way to do this, from the definition of
a fraction (splitting in equal parts). If so, how are the weights
$\omega$ calculated?  Intuitively, $\omega$ must be:
$$
\frac{x/y}{x/y+a/b}
$$
Is this correct? What would $\phi$ be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you try to get an expresion kind of:

$$
A=\frac{\phi x+\gamma a}{\omega y+\left(1-\omega\right)b}
$$

Note we just need to fix the denominator, and we have an unknown $w$ to play with so:
$$
yb=wy+(1-w)b\\
yb = wy + b - wb\\
yb-b = wy - wb\\
(y-1)b = w(y-b)\\
w=\frac{b (y-1)}{(y-b)}\\
$$

Then we have

$$
A=\frac{b x+y a}{xy} = \frac{b x+y a}{\frac{b (y-1)}{(y-b)} y+\left(1-\frac{b (y-1)}{(y-b)}\right)b}
$$

And finally, we have

$$
\phi = b \\
\gamma = y
$$

Comment: Seems intuitive, except for the (y-1) part. I would have thought it would just be y..